# create dynamic object for an array in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a combobox with textbox. here i need to create an object for an array in js through ajax.
ex:

```
var countries = {};
countries.results = [
    {id:'ZM',name:'Us'},
    {id:'ZW',name:'Ksa'}
];
```

how can i create an object for an array through ajax,php?

Comment: Probably relevant: http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. Please see the FAQ for tips on how to ask a good question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: how i can add some more values to that variable('countries') dynamically.Like, countries.push('{id:'jp',name:'jphn'}');
But it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add more values to `countries.results` array use

```
countries.results.push({id : "IN", name : "India"});
```